# Placeholder inside of IN-array

Tags: mysql

MySQL can't handle placeholders inside of the IN-array.
The query always got an empty result.
Does anyone know a solution for this problem?

```
SELECT * FROM table1 where column1 in ('abc.%', 'xyz.%');
```

Comment: Are you trying to match a prefix that _always_ ends with a `.`?

Comment: @SalmanA the id's are sorted with an tree strucure. As example: "node1; node1.node12; node1.node12.node123". I want to mach all id's starting with "node1.%"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What's wrong with using `LIKE` and `OR`?

```
SELECT * 
  FROM table1 
 WHERE column1 LIKE 'abc.%'
    OR column1 LIKE'xyz.%';
```

Comment: The array is created in php with about 2000 items. This is a possible solution, but i think it isn't efficient.

Comment: And? Construct the `OR` instead.

Comment: What makes you think it's ineffcient? This is the only real option, but looking at the format, I wonder if regular expressions might be more suited to your problem?

Comment: Thanks. I will try it with regex otherwise with the "where... like ..."

Comment: For what it's worth, `OR` will likely be far more performant than regex.

Comment: Looks more like a database design issue to me.

Comment: It's an currently about 2 TiB large database which was created by an application and can not be changed. That's why it's interesting which solution is the fastest, but the db-design is ok.

Comment: If you're creating a query with 2000 parameters, something is wrong with your data structures.